# creating 3 sub list from a single bigger list of person class

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, .net-4.0

I am having a List of Person

```
dim list As New List(Of Person)
```

' Lets says above list has 6 person objects with 3 types of ages Ex 25, 28, 35 years

I want to write a function which can generate 3 seperate list of person object grouped by age
and fill them in

```
dim masterList As New List(List(Of Person))
```

can you please suggest some code snippet to achieve this in Vb.net

Definition of person class

```
class Person

Dim age as Integer

Dim name as String

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy using linq to objects:

```
masterList = list.GroupBy(Function(p) p.age) _
                 .Select(Function(g) g.ToList()) _
                 .ToList()
```

You have to import `System.Linq` to make it work.

Comment: .Select(Function(g) g.ToList()) this line is not working VS is not accepting it , i m checking why

Comment: Check it now. I've updated my answer (forgot that's VB, and `_` makes that work)

Comment: yes yes , it also works when i wrote it all in single line anyways thanks a lot